# what is a required temperature of water for foaming of yeast??

Tags: baking, bread, temperature

What is the exact temperature of water for the foaming of yeast while baking because when i use cold it is does not activated similarly on hot water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lukewarm-- which is warm enough so that you can dip your hand into it without damage, but not so warm that you put your hand in and immediately have to yank it back out again. On my thermometer, when I use one, that's about 110 degrees Fahrenheit.